# Can index.html be used as home page and index.php as internal page?

Tags: php, html

This may sound like wanting my cake and eating it too so I am wondering if it is possible. 
We have a hosted estore using Zen Cart and full ftp access.

The idea is to be able to have a splash page as the first page seen when domain is accessed and then have a link to load the index.php file which will make navigating the site much easier for the client.

Answer (score 0):

Splash pages are generally an antipattern, but the better way to implement it would be to put the splash content in the same page as your index.php and then map index.php to the default page for the root domain resource (http://yourdomain.com/).  This also decouples php from your page URIs (URIs should not indicate backend technology).

You can use a number of javascript lightbox or modal dialog packages to get this effect for the first login and then avoid showing it later on.

Showing a splash page is an anti-pattern for usability since when people are visiting your site they generally want to do something or get something, not see a pretty splash page.  I have never gone to a website and been happy that they wasted my time with a big useless splash page.

Comment: Thank you for your help and insight regarding splash pages. I came up with the idea because our regular storefront was not engaging visitors. Our goal is to present our USP up front. Appreciate your response and will try both ways.